# How to manage a PDF digital signature's display?

Tags: pdf, certificate, itext, digital-signature, pdfstamper

I'm using iText Library to sign my PDF documents.
I want to know if there is any method in PdfStamper that could manage the display of the appearance : signature information in one layer, and the image in one other layer, which are now in the same layer:

*Solution :*

```
            PdfStamper pdfStamper;
            pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, null, '\0',
                        outputFile);

            // appearance
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfStamper
                        .getSignatureAppearance();
            appearance .setReason("Test");
            appearance .setLocation("Location");                                                                                                                                 
            appearance .setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE)); 
            appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION); appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(420, 732, 512, 780), 1,"sign");
```

Refering to this interesting [book](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf) , I can now create two areas for description and graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), section 2.4 "Creating different signature appearances." You'll learn about the layers n0 to n4, and discover that using layers n1, n3 and n4 is no longer recommended since 2003 (in other words: don't use them).

You can use the n0 layer, known as the background layer like this:

```
PdfTemplate n0 = appearance.getLayer(0);
float x = n0.getBoundingBox().getLeft();
float y = n0.getBoundingBox().getBottom();
float width = n0.getBoundingBox().getWidth();
float height = n0.getBoundingBox().getHeight();
n0.setColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
n0.rectangle(x, y, width, height);
n0.fill();
```

This is just a simple example from the book, drawing a light gray rectangle.

You can use the n2 layer like this:

```
PdfTemplate n2 = appearance.getLayer(2);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(n2);
ct.setSimpleColumn(n2.getBoundingBox());
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This document was signed by Bruno Specimen.");
ct.addElement(p);
ct.go();
```

If "drawing text" is too difficult, you can also use convenience methods such as:

```
appearance.setLayer2Text("This document was signed by Bruno Specimen");
appearance.setLayer2Font(new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN));
```

The examples from the book are available on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/).

Using the above methods, is creating the appearance "the hard way". There are also different ways to let iText do the work:

[image: Screen shot digital signatures book]

Comment: Thank you Mr Lowagie , actually The purpose is to get the signature display like that :  http://oi59.tinypic.com/2418k03.jpg

Comment: That was not your question, but fortunately that is also covered in the book I refer to in my answer.

Comment: It was very helpful Mr Lowagie Thank you!

Comment: Hello Mr @Lowagie, I would like to know how to make a digital signature valid whatever the computer used. Is there any requirements?

Comment: @Angelika The requirement is that every computer has a viewer that supports digital signatures, e.g. Adobe Reader.

Comment: Okey, but even I have pdf reader like Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, the digital signature still appear invalid in other machines. and the signer's identity is unknown. However, the signature is valid and the signer's identity is known and refers to the current user, when I sign the document in the same machine which the certificate is installed.

Comment: The "signer unknown" problem isn't related to the validity. Signer unknown means that the root certificate of the certificate chain isn't in the list of trusted identities. You are confusing two different concepts, which makes it hard to answer your question. (One could say that your question is invalid :D )

Comment: Please Mr @Lowagie how to make sure that the root certificate is in the list of trusted identities especially in a different machine?

Comment: Use a certificate that is purchased from a Certificate Authority (CA) that is either a member of CDS or that participates in [AATL](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html). AATL is the Adobe Approved Trust List. CAs pay Adobe to be on that list and Adobe distributes their root certificate to Adobe Reader. Implicitly this means that using free certificates is out of the question for you: no CA that provides free certificates is on the AATL. Your CA needs to be on [this list](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list1.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer